# Using the definition of the limit to show

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I am stuck an how to proceed in my proof. I am suppose to show, using the definition of the limit, that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 2}{(x^3-2x-4)/(x^2-4)=5/2}$.

I did some algebra with the $|f(x)-5/2|$ and got to the point where I have $|f(x)-5/2| \leq (1/2)|x-2||2x+3|$, but I am unsure how to procced in choosing my $\delta$... Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry, I should have been more clear; I need to do this using an epsilon and delta argument...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First $$\begin{align}\left|f(x)-\frac{5}{2}\right|&=\left|\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x+2}-\frac{5}{2}\right|\\&=\left|\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x+2}-\frac{10}{x+2}+\frac{10}{x+2}-\frac{5}{2}\right|\\&\leq\left|\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x+2}-\frac{10}{x+2}\right|+\left|\frac{10}{x+2}-\frac{5}{2}\right|\\&=\frac{|x^2+2x+-8|}{|x+2|}+\frac{|10-5x|}{|2x+4|}\\&=\left(\frac{|x+4|}{|x+2|}+5\frac{1}{|2x+4|}\right)|x-2|\\&\leq\left(\frac{|x-2|+6}{4-|x-2|}+\frac{1}{8-2|x-2|}\right)|x-2|\\&\leq(\frac{6+\delta}{4-\delta}+\frac{1}{8-2\delta})\delta\\&\leq(7/3+1/6)\delta\end{align}$$

Now just put $\delta=\min(1/(7/3+1/6),\epsilon/(7/3+1/6))$.

Above we used things like triangle inequality several times. E.g. $$|x-2+4|\leq |x-2|+4.$$
Or as in $$|x+2|=|4-(-(x-2))|\geq|4|-|x-2|.$$ Or in $$|2x+4|=|2(x-2)+8|\geq 8-2|x-2|.$$

> **To proceed from where you got it.**
>
> You have $$\begin{align}|f(x)-5/2|&\leq(1/2)|x-2||2x+3|\\&=(1/2)|x-2||2(x-2)+7|\\&\leq(1/2)(2|x-2|+7)|x-2|\\&\leq(1/2)(2\delta+7)\delta\end{align}$$

Comment: It seemed clearer in your example, but, how do I go about choosing my delta? It seems like I should let $\delta = min \lbrace (1/2)(2+7), (1/2)(2 \epsilon +7)\epsilon \rbrace$. Is this correct?

Comment: @phatty There are, of course, many choices. One could be $\delta=\min(2/9,2\epsilon/9)$. Notice that if $\epsilon\geq1$ you choose $\delta=2/9<1$. Then $(1/2)(2\delta+7)\delta<(1/2)9(2/9)=1\leq\epsilon$.

Comment: thanks for the clarification in the edit, it really helped.

Answer (score 3):

Note: OP edited question after I've posted this solution.

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x \to2}\frac{x^3-2x-4}{x^2-4}&=\lim_{x \to2}\frac{(x-2)(x^2+2x+2)}{(x-2)(x+2)}\\
&=\lim_{x \to2}\frac{x^2+2x+2}{x+2}\\
&=\frac{2^2+2\cdot2+2}{2+2}\\
&=\frac{5}{2}
&\end{align}$$

Comment: I know this... Is there more of a hint I can get?

Comment: sorry, I should have been more clear; I need to show this using a delta epsilon argument.

Comment: @Integrator i down voted because question is to be done using definition of limit i.e using deltas and epsilons not using this method

Comment: @Integrator What do  you think title of question suggests to you ?

Comment: @Integrator ok as i shall see. i donot want to get into anything.